# Typescript never type error during BehaviorSubject instantiation (never[] is not assignable)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my Angular project I'm trying to initialize `BehaviorSubject` property with an empty array:

```
export class Buffer {

  $items: BehaviorSubject<Array<Item>>; // or <Item[]>
  private _items: Array<Item>; // or Item[]

  constructor(settings: Settings) {
    this.$items = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  }
}
```

The typescript compiler throws the following error:

> error TS2322: Type '`BehaviorSubject<never[]>`' is not assignable to
>   type '`BehaviorSubject<Item[]>`'

I've tried to read about "never" type and I don't understand why I'm getting such an error. Also, if I replace the `$items` instantiation with `this.$items = new BehaviorSubject(new Array())` there will be no error. But my IDE rightly warns me in that case: "Array instantiation can be simplified".

What is the problem and should I do here? I'm using typescript 2.7.2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to pass on the type parameter explicitly to the constructor

```
this.$items = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);
```

If the compiler has no other information `[]` will be inferred to `never[]`